# Image size in nested rows with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, image, grid, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create the following layout:

[image: layout]

But I am struggling to force the height of the 3 images on the right to not expand past the height of the left image. This is what I have currently;

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528463104570-9b313927fbca?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=b2815b93860831943ffdb596ed4b8668"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468898203265-d5b5601865c7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=a02d4618cdbf5cf692c5dba45c3ac028"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476483547798-bf769a2cbba5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=bc78be3e84a52b29ec28309d5de33c25"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513804191723-238c2f3c66f9?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=a58c1bc2427d9e45c5d8d7bc69e54aa0"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/sixstring666/pen/ejyZXM

I am using Bootstrap because it handles the image responsiveness for me (such as stacking the images in a single column when the viewport is small) but maybe it is not the way to go here?

Comment: yes, this is not the way. you should proper size images with height specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure that this is the best solution, as I think you will lose the responsive functionality and you'll need to edit your images, however I hope it could help:

```css
.bigger {
   height: 300px !important;
  }
  
  .smaller {
   height: 99px !important;
   margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row main">
    <div class="col-sm-6"> <img class="card-img img-fluid bigger" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528463104570-9b313927fbca?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=b2815b93860831943ffdb596ed4b8668"/> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-sm-12"> <img class="card-img img-fluid smaller" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468898203265-d5b5601865c7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=a02d4618cdbf5cf692c5dba45c3ac028"/> </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12"> <img class="card-img img-fluid smaller" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476483547798-bf769a2cbba5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=bc78be3e84a52b29ec28309d5de33c25"/> </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12"> <img class="card-img img-fluid smaller" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513804191723-238c2f3c66f9?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=a58c1bc2427d9e45c5d8d7bc69e54aa0"/> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the height of the images on both sides.